# Python Bokeh: Restart X axis to 0 on Zoom

Tags: python, bokeh

I have code below that creates a simple line x-y plot.

When I zoom in, I want the x-axis ticker to start at 0 again instead of 3.9/whatever the x point of the zoom was as in the image.

No Zoom:

[image]

After Zooming:

[image]

How do I do that?

Code:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, save
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

data = []
x = list(range(11))
y0 = x
y1 = [10 - xx for xx in x]
y2 = [abs(xx - 5) for xx in x]
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y0=y0, y1=y1, y2=y2))
for i in range(3):
    p = figure(title="Title " + str(i), plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
    if len(data):
        p.x_range = data[0].x_range
        p.y_range = data[0].y_range

    p.circle('x', 'y0', size=10, color="navy", alpha=0.5, legend_label='line1', source=source)

    p.legend.location = 'top_right'
    p.legend.click_policy = "hide"
    data.append(p)
plot_col = column(data)
# show the results
show(plot_col)
```

Comment: You need to describe the interaction that you want in more detail, because I don't really understand what you are asking for. The `BoxZoomTool` zooms to exactly the area underneath the selected box. In general, it would be confusing and not make sense for it to do anything different than that.

Comment: @bigreddot If I have the xaxis with xrange 0>10, I zoom in to 4>7, The x axis will read 4>7. I want it to read 0>3, see edited image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unusual requirement, and none of the built-in things behave this way. If you zoom in to the interval *[4,7]*, the the range will be updated *[4, 7]*, and so then the axis will display labels for *[4, 7]*. If it will suffice to simply display different tick labels, even while the underlying range start/end remain their usual values, then you could use a Custom Extension to generate whatever customized labels you want. There is an example in the User's Guide that already does almost exactly what you want already:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions_gallery/ticking.html#userguide-extensions-examples-ticking

You might also be able to do something even more simply with a [`FuncTickFormatter`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#functickformatter), e.g. (untested)

```
p.xaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code="""
    return tick - ticks[0]
""")
```

Comment: I can use the custom formatter, but How do I get the xrange of the plot when I zoom? (I'm assuming I'd use that xrange as the min 0 value)